# Magento tier pricing using configurable products and custom options to display pricing table

Tags: php, magento

I am developing a website on Magento and the layout/functionality i would like to achieve is: http://route1print.co.uk/printing-products/business-cards-450gsm-silk-?productTypeId=3#?pt=3&lt=5&ps=57&pat=40&prt=1

The ideal goal functionality is to display a table as such showing different pricing of the product based on quantity and delivery date.

I have tried to achieve so using the standard magento installation. I have looked around the web and the closest tutorial/guide i have seen is http://www.code4business.de/tier-prices-for-magento-custom-options-en/

What i believed would have achieved the desired functionality was using Magento tier pricing based on the quantity and using the custom options to defer the prices for each quantity dependent on the end user's chosen delivery. However, Magento's custom options by standard doesn't allow you to add different tier pricing custom options.

Following the guide i have attempted to use both extensions and following the code written by the developer without success.

I am happy to switch the project unto woocommerce if woocommerce is easier or offers the functionality in order to produce a pricing table as such using tier pricing/varients.

My question is, weither Woocommerce or Magento, what are my options to developing a pricing table as such?

Thank you in advance

Kieren.